# Arch linux 2022: TikZ sets color to default in XeLaTeX but not in pdfLaTeX or LuaLaTeX (Is it a bug?)

Tags: tikz-pgf, xetex

**Old Post: (See solution below)**

See the below example:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=table,leqno,aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\newcommand\tikzmark[2][]{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,#1]\coordinate(#2);\end{tikzpicture}}


\begin{document}

  
  \begin{frame}
    \footnotesize
    \color{red}$\chi_R =\tikzmark{1} test$
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The output with `pdflatex` or `lualatex` is the expected red :

[image]

But `xelatex` compilation gives the below output:

[image]

PS: Just used a custom `\tikzmark` that is an almost plain TikZ environment. Don't suggest the library please. It is for testing tikzpicture purposes

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999994 (TeX Live 2022/Arch Linux) (preloaded format=xelatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2022-04-10>
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamer.cls
Document Class: beamer 2022/02/08 v3.66 A class for typesetting presentations
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasemodes.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasedecode.sty))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbaseoptions.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifvtex.sty))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/math/pgfmath.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.tex
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common-lists.tex))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.def)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.code.tex
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/pgf.revision.tex)))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeysfiltered.code.tex)))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.code.tex
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.trigonometric.code
.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.random.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.comparison.code.te
x) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.base.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.misc.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.integerarithmetics
.code.tex))) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.code.tex)
)) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/leqno.clo)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size11.clo)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/xetex.def)))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.code.tex
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgf.cfg)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-xetex.def
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-dvipdfmx.def
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-common-pdf.def))))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsysprotocol.code.tex))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/colortbl/colortbl.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/array.sty)))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.code.tex
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfint.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepoints.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex
) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathusage.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorescopes.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoregraphicstate.code.tex)

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransformations.code.t
ex) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorequick.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreobjects.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathprocessing.code.te
x) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorearrows.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreshade.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreimage.code.tex
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreexternal.code.tex))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorelayers.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransparency.code.tex)
 (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepatterns.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorerdf.code.tex)))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/xxcolor.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/atbegshi-ltx.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvdefinekeys/kvdefinekeys.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdfescape/pdfescape.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hycolor/hycolor.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/letltxmacro/letltxmacro.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/auxhook/auxhook.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/intcalc/intcalc.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/etexcmds/etexcmds.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/puenc.def)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bitset/bitset.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bigintcalc/bigintcalc.sty))

Package hyperref Message: Stopped early.

) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hxetex.def
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/stringenc/stringenc.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/rerunfilecheck/rerunfilecheck.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/atveryend-ltx.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/uniquecounter/uniquecounter.sty)))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbaserequires.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasecompatibility.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasefont.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/sansmathaccent/sansmathaccent.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlfile.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlfile-hook.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlogo.sty)))))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasetranslator.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/translator/translator.sty))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasemisc.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasetwoscreens.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbaseoverlay.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasetitle.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasesection.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbaseframe.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbaseverbatim.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbaseframesize.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbaseframecomponents.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasecolor.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasenotes.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasetoc.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasetemplates.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbaseauxtemplates.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbaseboxes.sty)))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbaselocalstructure.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/enumerate.sty))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasenavigation.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasetheorems.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amscls/amsthm.sty))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasethemes.sty))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerthemedefault.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerfontthemedefault.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamercolorthemedefault.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerinnerthemedefault.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerouterthemedefault.sty)))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgf.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleplot.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgffor.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code.tex
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex)))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryplothandlers.code.te
x) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmodulematrix.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrary
topaths.code.tex)))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrary
calc.code.tex) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-xetex.def)
(./test.aux) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd)
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: xetex
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/refcount/refcount.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/gettitlestring/gettitlestring.sty))
(./test.out) (./test.out)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/translator/translator-basic-dictionary-English
.dict)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/translator/translator-bibliography-dictionary-
English.dict)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/translator/translator-environment-dictionary-E
nglish.dict)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/translator/translator-months-dictionary-Englis
h.dict)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/translator/translator-numbers-dictionary-Engli
sh.dict)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/translator/translator-theorem-dictionary-Engli
sh.dict) (./test.nav) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd) [1] (./test.aux)

 *File List*
  beamer.cls    2022/02/08 v3.66 A class for typesetting presentations
beamerbasemodes.sty    
etoolbox.sty    2020/10/05 v2.5k e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
beamerbasedecode.sty    
   iftex.sty    2022/02/03 v1.0f TeX engine tests
beamerbaseoptions.sty    
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
geometry.sty    2020/01/02 v5.9 Page Geometry
  ifvtex.sty    2019/10/25 v1.7 ifvtex legacy package. Use iftex instead.
 pgfmath.sty    
  pgfrcs.sty    2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
pgfrcs.code.tex
 pgfkeys.sty    
pgfkeys.code.tex
pgfmath.code.tex
   leqno.clo    2016/12/29 v1.2b Standard LaTeX option (left equation numbers)
  size11.clo    2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
 pgfcore.sty    2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
graphicx.sty    2021/09/16 v1.2d Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
graphics.sty    2021/03/04 v1.4d Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    2021/08/11 v1.11 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
   xetex.def    2022/04/12 v5.0l Graphics/color driver for xetex
  pgfsys.sty    2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
  xcolor.sty    2021/10/31 v2.13 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
colortbl.sty    2020/01/04 v1.0e Color table columns (DPC)
   array.sty    2021/10/04 v2.5f Tabular extension package (FMi)
pgfcore.code.tex
 xxcolor.sty    2003/10/24 ver 0.1
atbegshi-ltx.sty    2021/01/10 v1.0c Emulation of the original atbegshi
package with kernel methods
hyperref.sty    2022-02-21 v7.00n Hypertext links for LaTeX
 ltxcmds.sty    2020-05-10 v1.25 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2020-06-27 v0.33 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2019/12/03 v1.5 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2019/12/15 v1.18 Key value parser (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2019-12-19 v1.6 Define keys (HO)
pdfescape.sty    2019/12/09 v1.15 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
 hycolor.sty    2020-01-27 v1.10 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
letltxmacro.sty    2019/12/03 v1.6 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
 auxhook.sty    2019-12-17 v1.6 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2020-10-07 v3.14 Key value format for package options (HO)
  pd1enc.def    2022-02-21 v7.00n Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
 intcalc.sty    2019/12/15 v1.3 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2019/12/15 v1.7 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
   puenc.def    2022-02-21 v7.00n Hyperref: PDF Unicode definition (HO)
     url.sty    2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
  bitset.sty    2019/12/09 v1.3 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
bigintcalc.sty    2019/12/15 v1.5 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO)
  hxetex.def    2022-02-21 v7.00n Hyperref driver for XeTeX
stringenc.sty    2019/11/29 v1.12 Convert strings between diff. encodings (HO)
rerunfilecheck.sty    2019/12/05 v1.9 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
atveryend-ltx.sty    2020/08/19 v1.0a Emulation of the original atveryend packa
ge
with kernel methods
uniquecounter.sty    2019/12/15 v1.4 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
beamerbaserequires.sty    
beamerbasecompatibility.sty    
beamerbasefont.sty    
 amssymb.sty    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols
amsfonts.sty    2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
sansmathaccent.sty    2020/01/31
scrlfile.sty    2021/11/13 v3.35 KOMA-Script package (file load hooks)
scrlfile-hook.sty    2021/11/13 v3.35 KOMA-Script package (using LaTeX hooks)
 scrlogo.sty    2021/11/13 v3.35 KOMA-Script package (logo)
beamerbasetranslator.sty    
translator.sty    2021-05-31 v1.12d Easy translation of strings in LaTeX
beamerbasemisc.sty    
beamerbasetwoscreens.sty    
beamerbaseoverlay.sty    
beamerbasetitle.sty    
beamerbasesection.sty    
beamerbaseframe.sty    
beamerbaseverbatim.sty    
beamerbaseframesize.sty    
beamerbaseframecomponents.sty    
beamerbasecolor.sty    
beamerbasenotes.sty    
beamerbasetoc.sty    
beamerbasetemplates.sty    
beamerbaseauxtemplates.sty    
beamerbaseboxes.sty    
beamerbaselocalstructure.sty    
enumerate.sty    2015/07/23 v3.00 enumerate extensions (DPC)
beamerbasenavigation.sty    
beamerbasetheorems.sty    
 amsmath.sty    2021/10/15 v2.17l AMS math features
 amstext.sty    2021/08/26 v2.01 AMS text
  amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
  amsbsy.sty    1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
  amsopn.sty    2021/08/26 v2.02 operator names
  amsthm.sty    2020/05/29 v2.20.6
beamerbasethemes.sty    
beamerthemedefault.sty    
beamerfontthemedefault.sty    
beamercolorthemedefault.sty    
beamerinnerthemedefault.sty    
beamerouterthemedefault.sty    
    tikz.sty    2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
     pgf.sty    2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty    2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty    2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
  pgffor.sty    2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
pgffor.code.tex
tikz.code.tex
l3backend-xetex.def    2022-04-14 L3 backend support: XeTeX
  ts1cmr.fd    2019/12/16 v2.5j Standard LaTeX font definitions
 nameref.sty    2021-04-02 v2.47 Cross-referencing by name of section
refcount.sty    2019/12/15 v3.6 Data extraction from label references (HO)
gettitlestring.sty    2019/12/15 v1.6 Cleanup title references (HO)
    test.out
    test.out
translator-basic-dictionary-English.dict    
translator-bibliography-dictionary-English.dict    
translator-environment-dictionary-English.dict    
translator-months-dictionary-English.dict    
translator-numbers-dictionary-English.dict    
translator-theorem-dictionary-English.dict    
    umsa.fd    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols A
    umsb.fd    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols B
 ***********

 )
Output written on test.pdf (1 page).
Transcript written on test.log.
```

**Solution for Arch based distros: [from [Here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/60905809) ]**

```
\documentclass[xcolor=table,leqno,aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\newcommand\tikzmark[2][]{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,#1]\coordinate(#2);\end{tikzpicture}}

\makeatletter
\AddToHook{cmd/endpgfpicture/after}{\special{pdfcolorstack \@pdfcolorstack current}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

  
  \begin{frame}
    \footnotesize
    \color{red}$\chi_R =\tikzmark{1} test$
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You probably need to specify which latex installation and version you're using. If I test using my TL22 then I get red text all cases. And also package versions (use `\listfiles` before `\documentclass`). Note that TeX version does not do much, code/format versions matters much more

Comment: I get red too in a current tex system.

Comment: Thanks @daleif ... I have already added the version ... just adding listfiles command and will update you

Comment: That is the tex version that is not really relevant. It does not even list which format version you're using.

Comment: Thanks @daleif ... Hope it is the right output now

Comment: I have to say it is a non-stable version possibly because of arch ... but it should possibly be reported since it is the latest uploaded code (I think)

Comment: you have various versions which are older than in a current texlive, where it works.

Comment: Thanks @UlrikeFischer ... We can close the Question (I don't use arch anyway :P ). It was just a client's request to test his code on arch.... I thought there are the most recent packages

Comment: I can't find the appropriate reason to close it here.... Please someone with more reputation can close it because of the reason provided by @UlrikeFischer ... Thanks!!!

Comment: you can always delete your own question.

Comment: Closing is better I think ... At least some arch users will find it helpful (and go back to debian :P)